# Fake DOS prompt on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm making an Easter egg in an iPhone app — making it look like the phone has crashed and is re-booting in DOS.

How do I create a plain text display with new lines appearing after small delays (i.e., making it look like the "computer" is rebooting, printing "BIOS" messages, etc.)?

I'm thinking it might be possible with some kind of text or label widget set to a monospace font? And appending text to it after periodic delays?

And would there be any way of faking a block cursor? That flashes?

Comment: Be sure to inform Apple of your Easter egg.  From Apple:  "If you want to add an innocuous Easter Egg to your application for that purpose, just use the demo Account Field to let the review team know the unlocking steps. Apple considers this information confidential and will not reveal those steps or their existence.

On the other hand, not telling the review team about an Easter Egg in your code in order to circumvent the review process is not allowed. When its existence becomes known, as it inevitable will, our first step will be to remove the offending application from the App Store."

Comment: Yep - I've got an Easter egg in an app in the store right now. I declared it in that form field, and had no problems; It's a dedication to my GF. For this new app, the Easter egg is part of the app's concept: it switches into an alternate reality / North Korean mode where things don't work so well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no "plain text" mode on iPhone, you need to draw nearly everything manually. The simplest solution would be to draw everything in your favorite graphics editor, and play a sequence of images as an animation: first, an image with only a prompt, then after a few seconds an image with the prompt and some text, then with some more text, and so on. Playing a beeping sound would add to the general excitement of it.

As far as the blinking cursor goes, you can use `CALayer` animation for it: make an image of a small white rectangle, place it in `CALayer` on top of your image with the text, and then animate its "visibility" property between "Yes" and "No" on a short timer, with the "repeat" flag set to "Yes".

Comment: Or just make an animated gif.